# Not every Urysohn space is semi-regular

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ Give an example of an Urysohn space which is not semi-regular .

$\mathbf {My \ approach}:$  Actually, it is an exercise problem from Willard's book( exc: $14F$) .
I tried some examples inspired from Sierpinski space, and slotted plane .

I think the slotted plane will work because if $N$ is a nhood of $z \in \mathbb R^2$ , then $N=\{z\} \cup A$ where $A$ is an usual open disc of $z$ with finitely many st lines through $z$ removed.
Then $cl(N) = A \cup \{\text{finitely many lines that were removed}\} \cup Fr(A)$
hence  $int(cl(N)) \neq N$ ; thus slotted plane isn't semi-regular .

But it's Urysohn, as real plane is Urysohn and removal of finitely many st lines doesn't affect anything.

I am still in some confusion , a small hint is warmly appreciated .

Comment: I corrected the spelling of "Urysohn". His orginal Russian name is "Урысон" which transcribes to "Uryson". The ending"son" in his name means exactly what it does in English. The German word for "son" is "Sohn" and that was used in  "Urysohn". See https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Urysohn/.

Comment: What is the slotted plane?

Comment: Never mind. I've looked at the definition and I think your solution is correct. You might want to verify that the closure of an open disk with lines removed is the closed disk with the lines filled in.

Comment: Yes person, I was trying to verify this thing about closure .

Comment: @PaulFrost: Since Russian for ‘son’ is сын, and Ukrainian is син, while Russian сон is ‘sleep’, I am skeptical of your assertion that the last part of his name means ‘son’; have you a source? The spelling *Urysohn* is more likely to be a German phonetic rendering: it captures the quality of the Russian vowel, though it gets the length wrong. And it is not incorrect to transcribe the name *Uryson*; I quite often do so myself, just as I usually use *Tikhonov* rather than *Tychonoff*.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott The y off in Tychonoff is French style transliteration, he used it himself for his French papers (in Fund. Math.) I believe. I don;t know if Urysohn wrote German papers (and what he himself chose for the transliteration)

Comment: @Henno: (If I’m not mistaken, the *-off* is also typically French.)  I found two papers by him in German in Math. Ann. (e.g., [this one](https://eudml.org/doc/159111)); both are posthumous publications, and in both he used *Paul Urysohn*.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott You are right, the Russian word for "son" is "сын" which would by "syn" in the usual transcription of Cyrillic letters to Latin letters. As you noticed in your last comment, in his Math. Ann. papers he used the name "Paul Urysohn". The reason is that he was Jewish, and his family name is most likely of [Yiddish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yiddish) orgin which is closely related to German (Urysohn =  Uris Sohn [German] = son of [Uri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uri_(name)) [English]). Cf. the name [Mendelssohn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mendelssohn_(disambiguation)).

Comment: @PaulFrost: Okay, that’s quite plausible, especially since I can’t find any likely Slavic basis for the surname. (Yiddish isn’t just related to German: after all, that could be said of English! It’s a descendent of Middle High German dialects, albeit with a great deal of its lexicon derived from Hebrew, Aramaic, and eventually also Slavic.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott English and German have certainly common ancestors, but the relationship between Yiddish and German is closer. You are right, there are many Yiddish words of non-German origin, but a Yiddish text is (essentially)  understood by German speakers. And I doubt that Урысон would have translated his name to "Paul Urysohn" if he would have known that Germany became what is was in the Nazi era.

Comment: @PaulFrost: I know that it’s closer; I just said so. That was precisely my point: that it is not *merely* related to German, but an actual descendent of a historical stage of the German dialects. (My main academic interest outside of mathematics is historical linguistics.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott See also https://dbs.anumuseum.org.il/skn/en/c6/e261780/Family_Name/URISOHN